# прокрутка в firefox

Tags: javascript, плагин

в firefox  прокрутка  работает не правильно((( подскажите пожалуйста как это можно исправить что бы было кросбраузерно.

```
            $('.section1').bind('wheel', function(event){


                                 if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0 ) {
                                     $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);
                                     $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideLeft();

                                }
                                else {
                                    $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);
                                    $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
                                }

                            });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.section1').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
                if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0 || event.delta < 0) {//вниз
                    //...   
                } else if (event.originalEvent.detail > 0) {//вниз
                    //...   
                } else {//вверх
                    //...   
                }
            }
            return false;
        });
```